# Using Guice, how do I inject the super class's constructor parameters?

Tags: java, inheritance, dependency-injection, constructor, guice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guice with parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309450/guice-with-parents)

```
class Book{string title;}
class ChildrensBook extends Book{}
class ScienceBook extends Book{}
```

I want to inject book titles into the subclasses, for example, `childrensBook` should be assigned the title "Alice in Wonderland" and `ScienceBook` should get "On the Origin of Species".  How can I accomplish this with Guice?

(Note that I do not want to overwrite the `title` field in the subclass)

Comment: Is it really how the classes are defined? Can you modify the source code of these three classes or not? Do you have access to a setter for the color field in the subclasses?

Answer (score 5):

Previously asked and [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908982/403455):

Buried in the [Minimize Mutability](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MinimizeMutability) section of the Guice Best Practices, you'll find this guideline:

> Subclasses must call `super()` with all dependencies. This makes
>   constructor injection cumbersome, especially as the injected base
>   class changes.

In practice, here's how to do it using constructor injection:

```
public class TestInheritanceBinding {
   static class Book {
      final String title;
      @Inject Book(@Named("GeneralTitle") String title) {
         this.title = title;
      }
   }
   static class ChildrensBook extends Book {
      @Inject ChildrensBook(@Named("ChildrensTitle") String title) {
         super(title);
      }
   }
   static class ScienceBook extends Book {
      @Inject ScienceBook(@Named("ScienceTitle") String title) {
         super(title);
      }
   }

   @Test
   public void bindingWorked() {
      Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
         @Override protected void configure() {
            bind(String.class).
            annotatedWith(Names.named("GeneralTitle")).
            toInstance("To Kill a Mockingbird");
            bind(String.class).
            annotatedWith(Names.named("ChildrensTitle")).
            toInstance("Alice in Wonderland");
            bind(String.class).
            annotatedWith(Names.named("ScienceTitle")).
            toInstance("On the Origin of Species");
         }
      });
      Book generalBook = injector.getInstance(Book.class);
      assertEquals("To Kill a Mockingbird", generalBook.title);
      ChildrensBook childrensBook = injector.getInstance(ChildrensBook.class);
      assertEquals("Alice in Wonderland", childrensBook.title);
      ScienceBook scienceBook = injector.getInstance(ScienceBook.class);
      assertEquals("On the Origin of Species", scienceBook.title);
   }
}
```

Comment: -1, sorry. The page that you link to does not say what you claim it does; you've pulled a quotation out of context in a way that dramatically changes its meaning. As a result, you are recommending an approach that is specifically called out as inferior by that source.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be writing the subclass constructors with different parameter annotations -- something like

```
class ChildrensBook extends Book {
  @Inject ChildrensBook (@AliceInWonderland String title) {
     super(title);
  }
}
```